# Why isn't Matlab returning palindromic numbers?

Tags: matlab

I have created the following code:

```
A = [0:1:999].*[0:1:999]';
B = mat2str(A);
B(B == fliplr([B]))
```

And was hoping that it would filter by palindromic numbers (same forwards and backwards e.g. 99, 101, 97479 etc).  I'm getting numbers that are not palindromic what is wrong with my code?

Comment: First of all, you code doesn't run (and it won't since it has dimension mismatch error in the first line)

Comment: Maybe OP is running it in Octave? Octave will expand orthogonal vectors in to 2-D arrays, so line 1 will produce a 1000-by-1000 array.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
A = [0:1:999].*[0:1:999];
B = str2num( fliplr( num2str(A')))';
palNums = A(A == B);
```

`palNums` should contain only palindromic numbers now.

Comment: +1 We should include an explanation: The reason OP's code isn't working is that `mat2str` will convert the big 2-D array to a single long string of chars (containing the Matlab expression to reproduce that array). What you really want is to produce a corresponding array of strings, and then to flip the strings individually. `num2str` does this because when called on a column vector, it'll produce a list of strings (represented as 20d char), and `fliplr` will do the "right" thing on them.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it as follows:

```
A=10:999999;   %I am assuming you want to start from 10 since a single digit will always be palindrome.

for i=1:length(A)
    digits1 = sscanf(strrep(num2str(A(i),10),'.',''),'%1d')'; %If you want to support 
               %numbers more than 10 digits, replace above number accordingly.
    digits2=fliplr(digits1);
    if digits1==digits2
       palindrome(i)=1;
       fprintf('A palindrome\n');
    else
       palindrome(i)=0;
       fprintf('Not a palindrome\n');
    end
end
```